# How can I tell what class in the polymorphic hierarchy contains the method I'm about to call?

Tags: python, polymorphism, introspection

If I have:

```
class A():
    def f(self):
        print("running function, f from class A")
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
    def f(self):
        print("running function, f from class B")
```

and I make an instance of class B and call f on it, we all know we'll see the message about "from class B." But is there a way for me to inspect my object and make sure my sub-class has overridden my method? Something like:

```
obj = B()
assert(not obj.f.livesIn(A))
```

Comment: Does this answer give you what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484890/how-would-you-determine-where-each-property-and-method-of-a-python-class-is-defin/485550#485550 - it begins "You are looking for the undocumented function `inspect.classify_class_attrs(cls)`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force the child class to override, you can `raise NotImplementedError()`.

Doing the inspection is possible too... And I see unutbu just posted an example, so I won't repeat it. :)

Comment: Previously, I said that you could use the abc module for this, but I wasn't thinking clearly. :) In python, an abstract base class is like a java interface rather than a java-style abstract class. NotImplementedError is the traditional way to emulate java's abstract keyword.

Answer (score 3):

```
class A():
    def f(self):
        print("running function, f from class A")
class B(A):
    def f(self):
        print("running function, f from class B")
class C(A):
    pass
```

This shows that `B.f` does not equal `A.f`. So `B` must override `f`:

```
obj = B()
print(obj.__class__.f == A.f)
# False
```

This shows that `C.f` equals `A.f`. So `C` must not have overridden `f`:

```
obj = C()
print(obj.__class__.f == A.f)
# True
```

Comment: Perfect, and much simpler than I was making it. Thank you. :)

Comment: oops, spoke too soon. If you run it against self in a constructor of a super-class, it doesn't work. :(

Comment: When a superclass constructor is called, the object is of the superclass type. It's morphed to the subtype only when the subtype constructor is called