# Detecting bound method in classes (not instances) in Python 3

Tags: python, function, methods, introspection

Given a class `C` with a function or method `f`, I use `inspect.ismethod(obj.f)` (where `obj` is an instance of `C`) to find out if `f` is bound method or not. Is there a way to do the same directly at the class level (without creating an object)?

inspect.ismethod does not work as this:

```
class C(object):

    @staticmethod
    def st(x):
        pass

    def me(self):
        pass

obj = C()
```

results in this (in Python 3):

```
>>> inspect.ismethod(C.st) 
False
>>> inspect.ismethod(C.me)
False
>>> inspect.ismethod(obj.st) 
False
>>> inspect.ismethod(obj.me)
True
```

I guess I need to check if the function/method is member of a class and not static but I was not able to do it easily. I guess it could be done using `classify_class_attrs` as shown here 
[How would you determine where each property and method of a Python class is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484890/how-would-you-determine-where-each-property-and-method-of-a-python-class-is-defi)
but I was hoping there was another more direct way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no unbound methods in Python 3, so you cannot detect them either. All you have is regular functions. At most you can see if they have a [qualified name with a dot](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-qualified-name), indicating that they are *nested*, and their first argument name is `self`:

```
if '.' in method.__qualname__ and inspect.getargspec(method).args[0] == 'self':
    # regular method. *Probably*
```

This of course fails entirely for static methods and nested functions that happen to have `self` as a first argument, as well as regular methods that do not use `self` as a first argument (flying in the face of convention).

For static methods and class methods, you'd have to look at the *class dictionary* instead:

```
>>> isinstance(vars(C)['st'], staticmethod)
True
```

That's because `C.__dict__['st']` is the actual `staticmethod` instance, before [binding to the class](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `inspect.isroutine(...)`? Running it with your class `C` I get:

```
>>> inspect.isroutine(C.st)
True
>>> inspect.isroutine(C.me)
True
>>> inspect.isroutine(obj.st)
True
>>> inspect.isroutine(obj.me)
True
```

Combining the results of `inspect.isroutine(...)` with the results of `inspect.ismethod(...)` may enable you to infer what you need to know.

**Edit:** dm03514's answer suggests you might also try `inspect.isfunction()`:

```
>>> inspect.isfunction(obj.me)
False
>>> inspect.isfunction(obj.st)
True
>>> inspect.isfunction(C.st)
True
>>> inspect.isfunction(C.me)
False
```

Though as Hernan has pointed out, the results of `inspect.isfunction(...)` change in python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Since inspect.ismethod returns True for both bound and unbound methods in Python 2.7 (ie., is broken), I'm using:

```
def is_bound_method(obj):
    return hasattr(obj, '__self__') and obj.__self__ is not None
```

It also works for methods of classes implemented in C, e.g., int:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> is_bound_method(a.__add__)
True
>>> is_bound_method(int.__add__)
False
```

But is not very useful in that case because inspect.getargspec does not work for functions implemented in C.

is_bound_method works unchanged in Python 3, but in Python 3, inspect.ismethod properly distinguishes between bound and unbound methods, so it is not necessary.

Comment: This is only useful for Python **two**, while the question specifically asks about Python **three**, where there are no unbound methods.