# List arguments of function/method and skip 'self' in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, self

Consider the following code:

```
args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(method)
if inspect.ismethod(method):
    args = args[1:]    # Skip 'self'
```

When running this on Python 2 and adding something with *self*, *self* is skipped (as mentioned in the comment). On Python 3, however I got trouble when using the code on `Class.method` (i.e. not `instance.method`). The problem is similar to [Detecting bound method in classes (not instances) in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408910/detecting-bound-method-in-classes-not-instances-in-python-3), but non of the answers there works. Using `inspect.isroutine()` or  `inspect.isfunction()` breaks the code for non-methods (no self). Using `hasattr(method, '__self__')` doesn't work on `Class.method`.

I've written a small testscript for this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import inspect


def args_without_self(method):
    args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(method)
    if inspect.ismethod(method):
        args = args[1:]    # Skip 'self'
    return args


class Class(object):

    def method(self, a, b, c):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def static(a, b, c):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def classmethod(cls, a, b, c):
        pass


def function(a, b, c):
    pass

instance = Class()

print(args_without_self(Class.method))
print(args_without_self(instance.method))
print(args_without_self(Class.static))
print(args_without_self(instance.static))
print(args_without_self(Class.classmethod))
print(args_without_self(instance.classmethod))
print(args_without_self(function))
```

The code works with both Python 2 and 3. However `args_without_self(Class.method)` also has *self* in Python 3 (and I would like to avoid that, but not break the others). Everythign should print `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, on Python 3, detect methods on the class, as they are *never bound*. They are *just regular functions*.

At most you can look at their [qualified name](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-qualified-name) and *guess* if they might be methods, then see if the first argument is named `self`. Heuristics and guesses, in other words:

```
if inspect.isfunction(method) and `.` in method.__qualname__ and args[0] == 'self':
    args = args[1:]    # Skip 'self'
```

Comment: And hope nobody would name self differently :(

Comment: @hroncok: or use `self` in a nested function, where it is not actually a method. But such are the limitations.