# Complete as-you-type on command line with python

Tags: python, shell, command-line, readline

I would like to write a small application/directory/file launcher in python.
To make it fast i would like to autocomplete/autosuggest entries. But i want to display
these suggestions as the user types. From what i have read about the readline module completion is
only possible using a "Completion hotkey" e.g. Tab.

Any suggestions ?

Using curses with filter as suggested below does not seem to work. This minimal example clears my screen despite the call to filter():

```
import curses

curses.filter()
win = curses.initscr()

curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()


while 1:
  key = win.getkey()
  win.echochar(key)
  if key == "Q":
    break

curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try with "curses" library:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html

You have a related topic at:

[How to make python autocompletion display matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869121/how-to-make-python-autocompletion-display-matches)

Comment: Curses would work i guess, however it seems to clear the screen which would cause bad integration with the shell

Comment: @joekr You are right, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772061/curses-library-c-getch-without-clearing-screen someone asked for a solution for the same problem (screen clearing) and got a solution for curses using C language just calling newterm instead initscr. Nevertheless, I think  that solution doesn't apply here because python curses library doesn't offer "newterm" method.

Comment: @joekr I have just found that you can override the initial screen clearing using the "filter" method:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.filter