# Display inverse video text with python on terminal

Tags: python, curses, termcap

Python has a `curses` module. Is there a simple way to use this module to display inverse video text? I don't want to do the full-blown curses application, just want the text to bring inverse (or in color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.filter) function (before [`initscr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.initscr)), the curses application will only update the current line of the screen (and will not clear the whole screen).  That would be a minimal use of the *curses* library.

If you want a lower-level (no optimization, do it yourself), you would have to use the *terminfo* level of the library, i.e., these functions:

- `initscr` with `filter` (since Python curses apparently has no interface to [newterm](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-newterm))
- [`tigetstr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.tigetflag) to read the capabilities for `sgr`, `sgr0`, `smso`, `rmso`, `rev`
- [`tparm`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.tparm) to format parameters for `sgr` if you use that
- [`putp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.putp) to write the strings read/formatted via `tigetstr` and `tparm`

The page *[Python curses.tigetstr Examples](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/51707/curses.tigetstr)* has some (mostly incomplete) examples using `tigetstr`, and reminds me that you could use [`setupterm`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.setupterm) as an alternative to `newterm`.  If you visit that page searching for "curses.filter", it asserts there are examples of its use, but reading, I found nothing to report.

Further reading:

- [Complete as-you-type on command line with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310392/complete-as-you-type-on-command-line-with-python) (shows `filter` in use)

A demo with reverse-video:

```
import curses

curses.filter()
stdscr = curses.initscr()
stdscr.addstr("normal-")
stdscr.addstr("Hello world!", curses.A_REVERSE)
stdscr.addstr("-normal")
stdscr.refresh()
curses.endwin()
print
```

or

```
import curses

curses.setupterm()
curses.putp("normal-")
curses.putp(curses.tigetstr("rev"))
curses.putp("Hello world!")
curses.putp(curses.tigetstr("sgr0"))
curses.putp("-normal")
```

illustrates a point: text written with `curses.putp` bypasses the curses library optimization.  You would use `initscr` or `newterm` to use the curses screen-optimization, but `setupterm` to not use it, just using the low-level capability- and output-functions.

Comment: Yes, I discovered that python has no interface to `terminfo`. Do you know of an example that shows `initscr` with `filter`?

Comment: Not offhand in python - the [ncurses-examples](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html) have an example `filter.c` in C.  But the functions I listed for terminfo are documented as part of python's C binding.

Comment: You aren't aware of a python example?